# PHP & HTML - echo li tag without break line

Tags: php, html

i have this code:

```
 <ol>
    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
    <li>
        <img src="public_html/images/example.jpg" height="250" width="250">
        <br />
        <a href="public_html/article.php?id=<?php echo 
$article['article_id'];?>">
            <?php echo $article['article_title'];?>
        </a>
        - <small>
            posted <?php echo date('l jS', $article['article_timestamp'])?>
        </small>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ol>
```

now it's print my in this way:

```
img
title 
img
title
...
```

and i want it's print my like this:

```
img      img     img     ...
title    title   title
```

i try to break line or use in div tag but it's don't work.
how can I do this?

thank's

Comment: Have you tried resolving this yourself first?

Comment: This is the default behavior of Ordered and Unordered list (UL/OL) that the list items (LI) are block level elements. You have to give the li a style display:block-inline.

Comment: Think about using a framework like bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

One way is to go with [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) and your code would then look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <ol class="row">
    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
     <li class="col-sm">
        <img src="public_html/images/example.jpg" height="250" width="250">
        <br />
        <a href="public_html/article.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id'];?>">
           <?php echo $article['article_title'];?>
        </a>
      - <small>
           posted <?php echo date('l jS', $article['article_timestamp'])?>
        </small>
      </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Dont forget to install the bootstrap CSS file into your code [Quickstart to bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into something like CSS Grid to get the layout you want. But a simple way to solve this will be to float your list items to the left. Include the following style tags before your code:

```
<style>
ul li { float:left;}
</style>
<ol>
    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
    <li>
        <img src="public_html/images/example.jpg" height="250" width="250">
        <br />
        <a href="public_html/article.php?id=<?php echo 
$article['article_id'];?>">
            <?php echo $article['article_title'];?>
        </a>
        - <small>
            posted <?php echo date('l jS', $article['article_timestamp'])?>
        </small>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use simple css:

```
li {
display: inline-block;
}
```